# scaling different colors according to a heatmap

Tags: opengl, heatmap, colormap, palette

I have a set of different colors expressed in RGB float values in the unit intervall, i.e. red for instance is

glColor4f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);

with the fourth value being the alpha channel.

No I would like to adjust this color heatmap-style, i.e. pixels with an underlying scalar value close to 1 are appearing more intense than pixels with an underlying value near 0.

I chose this procedure

```
  float red{ value <= 0.57147f ? 446.22f * value / 255.f : 1.f };
  float green{ value <= 0.95f ? ((value - 0.6f) * 728.57f) / 255.f : 1.f };
  float blue{ 0.f };
```

My question is now, how I can generate a similar rgb distribution for several discrete colors, e.g. blue, purple, yellow, etc.

Comment: You could compute a luminance value and use that value to index into a 1d palette texture, where you put your heatmap gradations.  There's a discussion on infrared palettes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495390/thermal-imaging-palette

Comment: but this suggests that the respective color defines the brightness. But its the other way around. I have a predefined color and want to adjust that color (brightness etc.) according to some scalar value ranging between 0 and 1

Comment: What do you mean by "discrete color"? Why can they be used in your general formulas?

Comment: I just have some pre-defined colors, e.g. red (1.0, 0.0, 0.0), blue (0.0, 0.0, 1.0) and I want to adjust their "brightness" of both of them individually, i.e. cranking up or down the three floats of each color to make it appear darker and lighter respectively

Comment: you can use/construct any parametric gradient pattern you want or use something known like [visible spectra colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22681410/2521214) or [temperature of black body](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630970/2521214) just change dynamic range of your value to match the gradient input range....