# Select N evenly spaced out elements in array, including first and last

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of arbitrary length, and I want to select N elements of it, evenly spaced out (approximately, as N may be even, array length may be prime, etc) that includes the very first `arr[0]` element and the very last `arr[len-1]` element.

Example:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(17)
>>> arr
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
```

Then I want to make a function like the following to grab `numElems` evenly spaced out within the array, which must include the first and last element:

```
GetSpacedElements(numElems = 4)
>>> returns 0, 5, 11, 16
```

Does this make sense?

I've tried `arr[0:len:numElems]` (i.e. using the array `start:stop:skip` notation) and some slight variations, but I'm not getting what I'm looking for here:

```
>>> arr[0:len:numElems]
array([ 0,  4,  8, 12, 16])
```

or

```
>>> arr[0:len:numElems+1]
array([ 0,  5, 10, 15])
```

I don't care exactly what the middle elements are, as long as they're spaced evenly apart, off by an index of 1 let's say. But getting the right number of elements, including the index zero and last index, are critical.

Comment: Unless someone has any better ideas, I can only think of `np.round(np.linspace(0, 16, 4))`.

Comment: FYI - the array elements are arbitrary, just describing the positions of the elements I want to access. I'll try out the linspace code.

Comment: @JDS oh, in that case Divakar's extension should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To get a list of evenly spaced indices, use `np.linspace`:

```
idx = np.round(np.linspace(0, len(arr) - 1, numElems)).astype(int)
```

Next, index back into `arr` to get the corresponding values:

```
arr[idx]
```

Always use rounding before casting to integers. Internally, `linspace` calls `astype` when the dtype argument is provided. Therefore, this method is *NOT* equivalent to:

```
# this simply truncates the non-integer part
idx = np.linspace(0, len(array) - 1, numElems).astype(int)
idx = np.linspace(0, len(arr) - 1, numElems, dtype='int')
```

Comment: Hey, looking to try this but I'm getting: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. Is there a quick change I can do? On Python 3.5 I believe.

Comment: nvm, just gotta be careful on calling `len` for a numpy array, I just used `arr.shape[0]` and it's fine. I can see `idx` provides the indicies just how I want them. However `arr[idx]` doesn't work, so I'm looking for a small modification: `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: Here's my fix: `idx = np.round(np.linspace(0, len - 1, numElems, dtype='int'))`, where `len = arr.shape[0]`. Now `arr[idx]` now works as expected :)

Comment: There are no guarantee that there won't be any duplicate in the idx list if numElements is smaller or equal to len(arr). In my opinion that is a flaw

Comment: If `numElems` is larger than the length of the array `len(array)` this code will produce duplicate selections.

Answer (score 3):

Your GetSpacedElements() function should also take in the array to avoid unfortunate side effects elsewhere in code. That said, the function would need to look like this:

```
import numpy as np

def GetSpacedElements(array, numElems = 4):
    out = array[np.round(np.linspace(0, len(array)-1, numElems)).astype(int)]
    return out

arr = np.arange(17)
print(array)
spacedArray = GetSpacedElements(arr, 4)
print (spacedArray)
```

Comment: For compatibility with other types of arrays you may want to add a `.tolist()` to the indexed part.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know more about finding indices that match values you seek, also have a look at `numpy.argmin` and `numpy.where`. Implementing the former:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.arange(17)

def nearest_index(array, value):
    return (np.abs(np.asarray(array) - value)).argmin()

def evenly_spaced_indices(array, steps):
    return [nearest_index(array, value) for value in np.linspace(np.min(array), np.max(array), steps)]

print(evenly_spaced_indices(test,4))
```

You should keep in mind that this is an unnecessary amount of function calls for the initial question you asked as switftly demonstrated by coldspeed. `np.round` intuitively rounds to the closest matching integer serving as index, implementing a similar process but optimised in C++. If you are interested in the indices too, you could have your function simply return both:

```
import numpy as np

def GetSpacedElements(array, numElems=4, returnIndices=False):
    indices = np.round(np.linspace(0, len(arr) - 1, numElems)).astype(int)
    values = array[indices]
    return (values, indices) if returnIndices else (values)

arr = np.arange(17) + 42
print(arr)
print(GetSpacedElements(arr, 4))                            # values only
print(GetSpacedElements(arr, 4, returnIndices=True)[0])     # values only
print(GetSpacedElements(arr, 4, returnIndices=True)[1])     # indices only
```

Answer (score 1):

To get N evenly spaced elements from list 'x':

```
x[::int(np.ceil( len(x) / N ))]
```